# Excel: If a cell = 0 then display the last entries, column header

Tags: microsoft-excel

If "remaining balance" = 0, I want to display the column header(date) of the last entry in a portion of the row.
Example: P7=0, so I want it to find the last entry between H7-N7, which is J7. I then want Q7 to display J7's Column header in J6.

[image: Picture here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH

The MATCH will find the last cell in the range with a number:

```
MATCH(1E+99,I7:N7)
```

That relative column then can be passed to the INDEX to return the correct Date:

```
=INDEX($I$6:$N$6,,MATCH(1E+99,I7:N7))
```